# Xamarin forms Azure push notification Delayed

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

Hey everyone I recently developed a Xamarin forms mobile app (iOS and Android) which uses azure mobile services node.js as the back end and I implemented azure push notifications for Android. It should send me a notification when a record is inserted to the database. I get the notification to my phone but there is a huge delay (about 1 min) any help is much appreciated Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Push Notifications are not real-time and not guaranteed delivery.  Delays are very common - I've seen delays of up to 5 minutes for a push.  So 1 minute doesn't seem out of place.

Comment: Can please suggest me an alternative way to do this

Comment: If you want real time notification, you will probably want to use something like SignalR. Of course this may not help if your app is backgrounded or not running.

Comment: My app is integrated with a rest service so can i integrate SignalR with my service

Comment: I don't see why not.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc for an example.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianHall

Comment: Thanks @JamesLavery